# Dynamorio / drcov / drcov2lcov doesn't find any coverage

Tags: x86, instrumentation, instructions

I generate a drcov logfile as a test from ls with the following call:

```
PATH=~/Downloads/DynamoRIO-Linux-7.1.0-1/bin64:$PATH  drrun -root ~/Downloads/DynamoRIO-Linux-7.1.0-1 -t drcov -dump_text --  ls
```

It generates an output file drcov.ls.22556.0000.proc.log.

Then I try to convert this to lcov using the following call:

```
~/Downloads/DynamoRIO-Linux-7.1.0-1/tools/bin64/drcov2lcov  -input ./drcov.ls.22556.0000.proc.log
```

According to verbose output, drcov2lcov skips everything and generates no coverage.

I tried it with an own program that has been compiled with RelWithDbgInfo and it was the same. Using addr2line I can parse the addresses from the log file perfectly.

What is my error?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that it only works with -dump_binary flag and not -dump_text flag.

Comment: I created simple converter for files created with -dump_text flag: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2085045